# Changing up and down arrow with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why won't this jQuery change my image to a down arrow like I want it to? When a user opens a drop down, the up arrow changes to a down arrow. I'm doing this with an if else because I don't know any easier way, but it's not working. The arrow stays up the entire time, no matter how many times I click. Here is the jQuery. Should be all thats needed. Thanks!

```
    $("h3#mpcClients").click(function() {
            $("#hidden0").slideToggle(500); 

            var up = true;

            if (up == true) {

            $("td h3").css("background-image", "url(http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/images/arrowDown.png)");
            up=false;
          }
            else if(up == false) {
                $("td h3").css("background-image", "url(http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/images/arrowUp.png)");
            up=true;
            }
            });
```

Comment: could we please see the html that goes with this jquery

Comment: because you have "var up=true" in your clickhandler for one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and set up some css like so:

```
.up {
    background-image: url("http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/images/arrowDown.png")
}
.down {
    background-image: url("http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/images/arrowDown.png")
}
```

Make sure you set up the html to a default arrow direction like so:

```
<td>
    <h3 class="up">Some text</h3>
</td>
```

Now for the js to change the css classes of the element:

```
$("h3#mpcClients").click(function() {
        $("#hidden0").slideToggle(500);

        // This adds a class if the element doesn't already have it
        // if the element already has the class it will remove it.
        $("td h3").toggleClass("up down"); 
});
```

Comment: Beautiful. This will be much more maintainable.

Comment: This is a good solution but not one I wanted to implement. I just moved by variable outside the declaration. Thanks.. +1

Comment: @TommyCoffee You're welcome. One reason I would suggest implementing this answer is because it will be easier down the road if you want to use the same up/down images elsewhere. Then even farther down the road when you want to change the images you will only have to go to one place in your CSS to do so.

Comment: haha I actually ended up using this. I should have tried it first. Thank you! Much more efficient, you're right. But the other guy actually gave me a solution to the problem I posted, so I guess he deserved the answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: @TommyCoffee not giving the answer points to the user who supplied you the answer you used, shame on you. :P

Comment: @TommyCoffee You are able to click the green check mark to toggle answers to your questions. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 4):

Everytime the function is called it will set a var up to true.
It will go into this clause everytime

```
    var up = true;

    if (up == true) {

    $("td h3").css("background-image", "url(http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/images/arrowDown.png)");
    up=false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("h3#mpcClients").click(function() {
            $("#hidden0").slideToggle(500); 

            $("td h3").toggleClass('up');
});
```

In your css, by default add the rules for showing the down arrow and in a rule for `.up` set the background arrow image accordingly.

```
td h3 { background-image : url(http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/images/arrowDown.png);}

td h3.up { background-image : url(http://www.crm-newsletter.com/client-emails/images/arrowUp.png);}
```

Much neater.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function slideT(id)
{   

    var n=id.split(" ");
    $('#panel'+n[1]).slideToggle('fastest');

    if(n[2]=='up')
    {
        $('#img'+n[1]).find('img').remove();

        $('#img'+n[1]).find('td').append('<img src="../images/down.png" id="'+n[0]+' '+n[1]+' down" style="float:left" onclick="slideT(this.id)" >');

    }
    else
    {
        $('#img'+n[1]).find('img').remove();
        $('#img'+n[1]).find('td').append('<img src="../images/up.png" id="'+n[0]+' '+n[1]+' up" style="float:left" onclick="slideT(this.id)" >');        
    }    
}
</script>
```

this answer will open ur table panel wich its HTML is sth like this:

```
<tr  style="cursor: pointer" id="img">
        <td align="center">&nbsp;<?=$value?><img src="../images/down.png" style="float: left;" id="slide>" onclick="slideT(this.id)"></td>
    </tr>

<table class="list_row_container" style="display: none;" id="panel">
</table>
```